# Saving table in a .txt file

Tags: python, txt

I was wondering if you could help me with a rather simple bit of code that I got stuck on.

I have a table in .txt that looked like this:

| FileName | predOGT (C) |
| --- | --- |
| CTOTU-1_1.fasta | 31.30 |
| CTOTU-2_1.fasta | 21.39 |
| CTOTU-0_1.fasta | 11.31 |
| CTOTU-2_5.fasta | 42.32 |
| CTOTU-2_2.fasta | 34.33 |
| CTOTU-1_2.fasta | 35.34 |
| CTOTU-0_3.fasta | 23.35 |
| CTOTU-1_3.fasta | 64.36 |
| CTOTU-2_4.fasta | 33.37 |
| CTOTU-2_3.fasta | 27.38 |

Which I have successfully changed to look like this:

| OldFile | NewFile | predOGT_(C) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CTOTU-1 | 1 | 31.30 |
| CTOTU-2 | 1 | 21.39 |
| CTOTU-0 | 1 | 11.31 |
| CTOTU-2 | 5 | 42.32 |
| CTOTU-2 | 2 | 34.33 |
| CTOTU-1 | 2 | 35.34 |
| CTOTU-0 | 3 | 23.35 |
| CTOTU-1 | 3 | 64.36 |
| CTOTU-2 | 4 | 33.37 |
| CTOTU-2 | 3 | 27.38 |

Now I would like to save this new table to a new .txt table

Below is my code which so far allows only the last row to be saved in the `new_file.txt`.

Could you tell me what mistake I am doing?

```
filepath = 'original_file.txt'
new_filepath = 'new_file.txt'

with open(filepath, 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        new_line = line.strip()
        new_line = new_line.replace('_','\t').replace('FileName','OldFile\tNewFile').replace('predOGT (C)','predOGT_(C)').replace('.fasta','').replace('CTOTU-','')
        print(new_line)
        with  open(new_filepath, "w") as n:
            new = n.writelines(new_line)
```

Comment: WHY do you want to save it in a `.txt` ?

Comment: You are opening/creating the output file for every single line, so the end result will be just the last line. Use file mode "a" to append (rather than "w" which truncates) or, better still, only open the file once (earlier, outside of the loop).

Comment: Add all `new_lines` to a list then write the list to the new file.

Comment: That's **not** how text files look. Please provide what is actually in them in your question.

Answer (score 2):

By doing that

```
filepath = 'original_file.txt'
new_filepath = 'new_file.txt'

with open(filepath, 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        new_line = line.strip()
        new_line = new_line.replace('_','\t').replace('FileName','OldFile\tNewFile').replace('predOGT (C)','predOGT_(C)').replace('.fasta','').replace('CTOTU-','')
        print(new_line)
        with  open(new_filepath, "w") as n:
            new = n.writelines(new_line)
```

you are opening new_filepath for each `for`-loop turn in write (`w`) mode, which does remove existing content from it. If you want to added further data to existing file without erasing you need to use append (`a`) mode. Please run following snippets and observe what would happend in each case, first using `w` mode

```
with open("file1.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("uno\n")
with open("file1.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("dos\n")
with open("file1.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("tres\n")
```

then using `a` mode

```
with open("file2.txt","a") as f:
    f.write("uno\n")
with open("file2.txt","a") as f:
    f.write("does\n")
with open("file2.txt","a") as f:
    f.write("tres\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked like this:

```
n = open(new_filepath, "w")

with open(filepath, 'r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(new_line)
        n.writelines(new_line)
```

The new_filepath is opened before and then the indentation should be the same as the print() one to add every line that the loop goes through.